# Deserializing Data from Json to .Net Objects

Tags: json, windows-phone-7, deserialization

I know that there are many questions about this, but I just can not figure out how to solve this properly. 
I've receive from a server a JSON that looks something like this:

```
{
    "Applications":{
        "data":{
            "Aplication 1":[
                {
                    "index":1,
                    "name":"App1",
                    "groups":{
                        "Properties":[
                            {
                                "number":0,
                                "fields":{
                                    "primary":"primaryValue"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "Aplication 2":[
                {
                    "index":2,
                    "name":"App2",
                    "groups":{
                        "Properties":[
                            {
                                "number":0,
                                "fields":{
                                    "searchEngine":"icon",
                                    "url":"google",
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "Aplication 3":[
                {
                    "index":3,
                    "name":"Foursquare",
                    "groups":{
                        "Properties":[
                            {
                                "number":0,
                                "fields":{
                                    "incoURL":"socialURL.jpg",
                                    "nameSoc":"rectangle",
                                    "url":"http://www.name.com"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }

}
```

I am trying to use Json.NET to deserialized this.

I'm not sure how to translate this JSON format in a class in my Windows Phone application. I'm not even sure if this is possible sence, as it can be seen in the above JSON format "Aplication 1", "Aplication 2" and "Aplication 3" are different and also the fields name for each application may differ:
- for `"Aplication 1"` is just one: `"primary"`
- for `"Application 2"` are 2: `"searchEngine"` and `"url"`
- for `"Application 3"` are 3: `"incoURL"`, `"nameSoc"` and `"url"`

Comment: Why do you need a class? Deserializing it to an Map of key value pairs should be fine. obj["applications"]["data"]["application 1"]["name"]

Comment: @LastCoder: "Aplication 1", "Aplication 2" and "Aplication 3" are different - could be anything ....and I do not know what is it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend use Json.net because it will help you to deal with such complex json.

http://dorobantu.me/post/2010/08/22/Deserializing-JSON-to-anonymous-types-in-C.aspx

http://www.eugenedotnet.com/2010/12/windows-phone-7-serialization-json-net/

Comment: I want to use JSON.net (wrote in my question this also) but I did not figure out how to model my data (Object) ..and this is mainly because the JSON received from server is different almost each time..

Comment: I don't know what you exactly are doing but if you know all the properties, and you are able to specify all of them with json.net, you should be good. But of course, you may not want to do it manually because the example structure already look complex. Try to get scheme (xsd) file and see if you can convert to class with xsd.exe